# form submits even when validation fails

Tags: jquery, html, css

I really don't understand what's going on with the `input[type="file"]` fields.

```
<form class="container formContainer" id="needValidation" name="Info" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="labelText">Document <span class="asterisk">&#42;</span></p>
        <div id="doc">
           <img src="assets/images/Document.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="custom-file">
           <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="document" name="document" accept=".jpg, .png" onchange="uploadValidate(this,'doc','IDdoc','errorDivDoc');" required />
           <label class="custom-file-label" for="document">Choose file...</label>
           <div id="errorDivDoc" class="invalid-feedback">Please upload the document</div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <a onclick="submitInfo();" id="submitBtn" class="btn">submit</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

The JS

```
function uploadValidate(fileElement, imageDiv, bText, errorDiv) {
var fileName = $(fileElement).val();
var fileExt = ['jpg', 'png'];
var inputFileExt = fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

if ($.inArray(inputFileExt, fileExt) == -1) {
    alert("Only '.jpg','.png' formats are allowed.");
    return false;

} else {
    var fileSize = $(fileElement)[0].files[0].size;

    if (fileSize > 2097152) {
        alert("Maximum allowed file size is 2MB");
        return false;

    } else {
        var labelText = fileName.substr(12, fileName.length);
        $(fileElement).next('.custom-file-label').html(labelText);
        readURL(fileElement, imageDiv, bText);
    }
   }
}

function readURL(input, imageDiv, bText) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#' + imageDiv + ' img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#' + bText).val(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
}

function submitInfo() {
  var form = document.getElementById('needValidation');
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
  } else {
    submitInfoRegistration(); //to store in DB
  }
}
```

The thing is if a file upload is greater than 2MB, it displays an alert window with the error message but the form still gets submitted when i click submit. Im assuming the `input[type="file"]` becomes validated as soon as alert is displayed but I can't seem to find out why or where. This is not my code though. I also tried `onclick="return submitInfo();"` but got the same result.
What can I do so that the form is submitted only if a file of 2MB or less with certain extension is uploaded?

Comment: `form.checkValidity()` has nothing to do with your file upload function.

Comment: I'm guessing you have javascript _error_ in your console, and therefore the javascript is unable to prevent the form submission.  Open your developers' console, do a test - do you see an error appear in the console before the form submits?

Comment: Also - would be better to use event binding on the form submission, then use `event.preventDefault()`, and control submission that way...

Comment: Where do you set the variable `event` in `submitInfo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an `<a>` element in place of the submit button, you can simply give it an `href` that doesn't go anywhere.

```
<a href="#" onclick="submitInfo()" id="submitBtn" class="btn">submit</a>
```

Then it's not necessary to call `event.preventDefault()` in the `submitInfo()` function.

If you need to refer to the event in the function, you have to pass it as an argument, it's not a global variable.

```
<a href="#" onclick="submitInfo(event)" id="submitBtn" class="btn">submit</a>

function submitInfo(event) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the method I was just about to type

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

> Returns true if the element's child controls are subject to constraint validation and satisfy those contraints; returns false if some controls do not satisfy their constraints.

The `form.checkValidity()` will not call your `uploadValidate()` function as the latter is not a constraint.

You need to somehow notify in your submission that the upload is valid or not. To do that, you could set a boolean flag e.g. `isValidUpload` during the validation and, in addition to to `form.checkValidity()`, check the flag during submission.

```
// assuming the file is required based off your HTML
var isValidUpload = false;

function uploadValidate(fileElement, imageDiv, bText, errorDiv) {
    var fileName = $(fileElement).val();
    var fileExt = ['jpg', 'png'];
    var inputFileExt = fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    if ($.inArray(inputFileExt, fileExt) == -1) {
        alert("Only '.jpg','.png' formats are allowed.");
        isValidUpload = false;
        return false;
    }
    var fileSize = $(fileElement)[0].files[0].size;
    if (fileSize > 2097152) {
        alert("Maximum allowed file size is 2MB");
        isValidUpload = false;
        return false;
    }

    var labelText = fileName.substr(12, fileName.length);
    $(fileElement).next('.custom-file-label').html(labelText);
    readURL(fileElement, imageDiv, bText);
    isValidUpload = true;
}

function readURL(input, imageDiv, bText) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#' + imageDiv + ' img').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#' + bText).val(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

function submitInfo() {
    var form = document.getElementById('needValidation');
    if (!form.checkValidity() || !isValidUpload) {
        // where did you get event from?
        //event.preventDefault();
        //event.stopPropagation();
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
    } else {
        submitInfoRegistration(); //to store in DB
    }
    // prevent link from firing
    return false;
}
```

Also, add a `return` in your `onclick`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return submitInfo()" id="submitBtn" class="btn">submit</a>
```